# how to check host for web services

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have looked through other related questions but none of them giving me right approach.

i need to check my host availability  out my app. i am using reachability  APIs for host detection.
i use it as written below

```
self.hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"https://10.98.241.22:8080/arsys"];
[self.hostReach startNotifier];
```

even though host is available, it gives connection status as 'Not Reachable' in following code

```
NetworkStatus netStatus = [self.hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];
```

Please help me and let me know that where i am doing wrong.

do i need to use `reachabilityWithAddress` for this type of Host URL. if Yes then please suggest me a sample example to use this API.

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Host name basically means a domain name, not a protocol (http/https) and IP address.

If you want to use an IP adress, try `-reachabilityWithAddress:`. It should look something like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(8080);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.98.241.22");
Reachability *addressReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&address];
```

Don't forget to `#include <arpa/inet.h>`

***Edit – 4 years later***

The modern and proper way to solve this would be to use something like [AFNetworkReachabilityManager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m) which also allows to check what kind of internet connection is available.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it is working for me.. but just a small doubt...do we also need to check internet connectivity with this Host check ?

Comment: @vikas No, since you will not be able to reach the address without an internet connection.

Comment: Hi HWaxxer, today server is down and this ip and this URL 'https://10.98.241.22:8080/arsys' is not accessible through safari or windows, but still i am getting status as connection available. if i disconnect LAN or turn off the airport then only it says that host not reachable, if internet is connected then it always give status as host reachable even if its not rechable

Comment: **A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network stack, can leave the local device.** This means you may need to check for status 200 or similar using NSURLConnection. Hope that helps.

Comment: @hwaxxer That comment should totally be in the answer. From what I've tried `1.2.3.4` will always be Reachable if internet connection is available.

Comment: @Segev Yeah I would recommend looking into [AFNetworkReachabilityManager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to get "real" reachability status.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the code with another host like 'http://google.com/'? It could be something with the port, i'm not sure if the api supports that

Comment: Yes i used it with 'www.apple.com' and it was working fine . it gives as host available. but not with my URL 'https://10.98.241.22:8080/arsys' this URL is accessible through safari but here in API it gives its status as Not reachable.

Comment: and yes when i check internet connectivity then it is working fine.

Comment: then you should go with the answer of @hwaxxer using     -reachabilityWithAddress: